# Camera Cordova plugin issue on android

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My application uses ionic 1 and [cordova-camera-plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/). It is working fine on ios. However on android the first time it asks for camera permission and then app crashes, then when I try again I get the following error:
**file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.company.test/cache/.Pic.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()**

I appriciate any help.. Please find my code below:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    var cameraOptions = {
            quality: 100,
            targetWidth: 400,
            targetHeight: 400,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            correctOrientation: true
    };
       navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);

}

 function cameraSuccess(imageURI){
     $scope.$apply(function () {
        //some code
     });
 }

 //here is where i am getting the error 
 function cameraError(message)
 {
    console.log(message);
   //alert('Failed because: ' + message);
 }
```

Comment: That's not the Answer you want to hear, but Ionic 1 is way too old. You should Update your App to newest Version (v5 currently). Same Plugin is working fine for me, so could be related

Comment: Yeah, working on that but needed a hot fix..